# How can I stop a check box getting clicked without disabling it

Tags: html, css

I am still having trouble with checkboxes. They are small and hard to see. When I disable my checkbox it becomes even harder to see. The color of the check becomes lighter.

Is there another way that I can stop a checkbox from responding to a click. Maybe something with javascript / jQuery so that once a variable is set then when a checkbox is clicked it just returns straight back to its pre-click state.

Comment: Can you ass a screenshot of what you had in mind? This seems very unclear...

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to use something other than a checkbox here.

Comment: Why would you want to do something? could you please explain / demonstrate what exactly you are trying top acheive

Comment: Hello, Sorry if I was not clear. I want to use javascript to dynamically disable a check box so that it can no longer be clicked. However when I change the disabled attribute to true then it also dims the checkbox so it's difficult to see.  I want to keep the checkbox showing bright as possible.  So instead of setting disabled to true I want another way to make it so that even when the user clicks the check box then the click action is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using plain HTML with the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" readonly="readonly" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" />
```

or with jquery:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="disabled" />
```

js:

```
$('input.disabled').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```